# Binding CollectionViewSource through Converter not triggering Converter when Item is added

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, solid-principles

I need to show inside a textblock the number of elements from a CollectionViewSource, that are not of a certain type. I've tried to accomplish this by adding a Converter between the Text property of the TextBlock and the Collection, but the Converter is not triggered when I add items to the ObservableCollection bound to the CollectionViewSource. The collection does get changed, because if I bind directly to Count property, this will trigger the converter.

This is the CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="PatientRelatedWorkflowsCollection"
                              Source="{Binding PatientRelatedWorkflows}"
                              x:Uid="68cbfcf5481c43bdb83d6b31fe8ddc34">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <my:SortDescription PropertyName="Patient.LastName" x:Uid="cf8cdd34c5d14c049a27e46848aca60d" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Patient"
                                          Converter="{StaticResource WorkflowPatientGroupConverter}"
                                          x:Uid="d03e9b90df654454b5f5f7a8ee9cb1bf">
                </PropertyGroupDescription>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

Here is the binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CountNonConsultationWorkflowsConverter}}" />
```

And here is the Converter:

```
public class CountNonConsultationWorkflowsConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var workflowItems = value as ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Object>;
        if (workflowItems != null)
        {
            return workflowItems.Count(item => (item as WorkflowDataViewModel) != null && (item as WorkflowDataViewModel).WorkflowType != WorkflowType.ConsultPatient).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        return "0";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I managed to make it work by using a MultiBinding together with a MultiValueConverter like below. This one works, because "Count" property does trigger a PropertyChange, but I do feel it's a bit of a hack and would like to have a nicer solution.

```
   <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountNonConsultationWorkflowsConverter}">
                    <Binding x:Uid="eb26d2c0bdb94d18ab48d8e25ce5f5ea" />
                    <Binding Path="Count" x:Uid="5555c981fda94bc6ad823c2f1e94b0f1" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
```

Any idea on how I can do this better? I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are following MVVM pattern I would bind TextBlock to a property CountOfCertainType in ViewModel and remove the converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UpdateSourceTrigger to Explicit, and update it every time you add an item.

Comment: I need to keep in line with a MVVM pattern, so I don't want to access the control in code behind.